# display image from left to right php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>image</th>
        </tr>
            <?php 
                $query = "SELECT * FROM collage";
                $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="img/collage/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" target="_blank"><img src="img/collage/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
    </table>
```

hello genius programmers!
my above code display images like this:

[image]

and i wanted it to become like this :
[image]

Comment: One answer would be to remove the table completely and place the images inside a div, they would naturally flow left to right and fold to another line when space ran out in the div's width. Then with a little CSS you can make them look nicely spaced out man.

Comment: thank you @RiggsFolly your the man

Answer (score 3):

Set `<tr></tr>` out of `<?php ?>`

try this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>image</th>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <?php 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM collage";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
            ?>

                    <td><a href="img/collage/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" target="_blank"><img src="img/collage/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>"></a></td>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently looping for table rows. You need an inner loop for table cells in order to get the table design you've mentioned.

Here is a reference: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

It will be something like this:

```
<?php 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM collage";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
            ?>

                    <td><a href="img/collage/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" target="_blank"><img src="img/collage/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>"></a></td>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: You're welcome, if it worked you can approve the answer so other users can reuse it.